# unity3d nullreferenceexception

Tags: unity

i want to display a mesh sequence so i imported my obj files and found a script and partially edit it a bit.My project looks like this:

the script is this:

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

/**
 * Animate a mesh by cycling through different meshes.
 * @author bummzack
 */
public class MeshAnimation : MonoBehaviour {

```
public Mesh[] Meshes;
public bool Loop;
public float FrameDuration;

private int _index;
private bool _playing = true;
private float _accumulator;
private MeshFilter _meshFilter;

public void Start() 
{
    _meshFilter = GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
    _index = 0;
}

public void Update()
{
    _accumulator += Time.deltaTime;

    if(_accumulator >= FrameDuration){
        _accumulator -= FrameDuration;
        _index = (_index + 1) % Meshes.Length;

        if(_index == 0 && !Loop){
            Stop();
            return;
        }

        _meshFilter.mesh = Meshes [_index];
        print ("Hello World");
    }
}
```

}

the line that causes the problem is this:

_meshFilter.mesh = Meshes[_index];

and the problem shown in the console is this:

NullReferenceException
MeshAnimation.Update () (at Assets/MeshAnimation.cs:43)

i know it has something to do with Meshes[_index} being null but i cant find the solution because i think the Meshes array is properly filled.Can anyone suggest a solution?
Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Where do you initialize the meshes? In the editor?

Comment: Yes in the inspector i dragged and dropped every .obj frame i need in the Meshes[] array.

Comment: Does your gameobject have an actual MeshFilter component added to it?

Comment: Voting to close as "Too localized." The purpose of this site isn't best used for helping figure out small errors like a NullReferenceException.

Comment: Also, Bogdan is on the right track--it's highly likely that your MeshFilter is null because public arrays on MonoBehaviours such as Meshes basically always get assigned a reference at runtime, even if the length is 0.

Comment: I think the question works, even if just for the fact that the author didn't just paste all of his code and left it for us to search for the issue. He actually pinpointed the line which caused the exception.

Comment: It didnt have a mesh filter so i added it to my gameobject, but the problem persists.And thank you all for your input it is really appreceated because it is really important to me to get this working.

Comment: The problem persists on the same line? You added the mesh filter to the gameobject that has this script attached right? Not to a child gameobject of it.

Comment: I am sorry it doesnt persist. But the problem now is that the gameobject doesnt go through the frames and the mesh stays as is.
e.g it doent "move" (The frames are of a horse running)

Comment: I'm not sure how printing works under Unity since I never got it to do anything (nor did I try). Change print ("Hello World"); to Debug.Log("Hello World"); and let me know if your gameobject greets the world (in the debug console). I'd also edit my question so it doesn't seem localized anymore.

Comment: Guyz thank you SO much for your help it really helped me to finally get it working. I added the script to the child object in the hierarchy and it worked! And if you didnt tell me about the mesh filter i wouldnt have got it working. I am new to this so this was a rookie mistake. Thank you again so much, i appreceate your help!!

Comment: No probs, but now the question will remain in uncertain state unless someone closes it. Want me to put all the pieces together and post an answer so you can accept it?

Comment: Yes of course, sorry im new to this forum and i am just learning how it works. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

michael.bartnett made a good point in the comments, and the only object left to put the blame on is the `MeshFilter`. Be sure one is added via the editor as a gameobject component, otherwise `GetComponent<MeshFilter>()` will return `null`.

**Extra piece of advice!** Do this for every `GetComponent<T>` call:

```
SomeComponent = GetComponent<SomeType>();
if (SomeComponent == null)
{
    Debug.LogError("ERROR! Unable to get component in GameObject: " + this.name);
}
```

This will log an error message in the console every time a component is not found. It will help you a lot with debugging.

**Extra piece of advice #2!**
You can use the `[RequireComponent (typeof (YourComponent))]` attribute to make things easier. Take a look at this:

http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/RequireComponent.html

In short, setting `[RequireComponent (typeof (MeshFilter))]` in your script will force Unity to auto-add a MeshFilter component to any GameObject to which you add your script.